# Reading Input from file

Tags: java, arrays, input

How would I read in input from a file and save it to an array?
For example the file contains:

2

1 1 2 3

2 4 5

Where the first number (2) represents the number of arrays need.
The first number in the second line is the array ID followed by whatever should be in the array (1 2 3). Same for third line, so array 2 should contain 4 and 5.

So the two arrays should be:

array1: [1][2][3]
array2: [4][5]

Java please! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store all numbers in a array of int arrays:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c:\\temp\\text.txt"))) {

        int numberOfArrays = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        int[][] arrays = new int[numberOfArrays][];

        int i = 0;

        while (i < numberOfArrays) {
            String line = reader.readLine();

            if (line.isEmpty()) {
                continue;
            }

            String[] parts = line.split(" ");
            int[] lineNumbers = new int[parts.length - 1];

            // is "array id" really necessary? i am just ignoring it.

            for (int j = 0; j < lineNumbers.length; j++) {
                lineNumbers[j] = Integer.parseInt(parts[j + 1]);
            }

            arrays[i++] = lineNumbers;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are we doing homework service here?

Comment: no, just having fun, @SleimanJneidi

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use java8. Reading all lines of a file becomes easy. And the conversions, etc. can easily be solved with streams.

Untested example code:

```
private static int[][] read() {
    Path path = Paths.get("c:/temp", "data.txt");
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
        return lines

            // remove first line
            .skip(1)

            // convert line to array
            .map(l -> l.split("  "))

            // remove first colum
            .map(a - > Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 1, a.length))

            // convert to array
           . collect(Collectors.toArray());
    }
}
```